# How to Plot a unit vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, plot, random

I am trying to create 2 random points that have vectors that pass them in a random direction. Example shown below

[image: figure 1]

I tried creating 2 random points and 2 random unit vectors and using the function quiver to create the graph,

```
c = rand(1,2);
d = rand(1,2);

A = rand(2,1)-0.5;
B = rand(2,1)-0.5;
u = A/norm(A);
v = B/norm(B);

figure(3)
scatter(c,d)
quiver(c,d,u,v)
```

The quiver function doesnt really help and all I get is 2 points on a graph.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If c and d have dimensions 1x2, but A,B have dimensions 2x1, then: "Error using quiver (line 44)
The size of X must match the size of U or the number of columns of U."
If fix it ("A = rand(1,2)-0.5; B = rand(1,2)-0.5;"), then you will get a picture with 2 vectors

Comment: Does this answer your question? `quiver(c,d,u.',v.',0)`, as noted above your `u` and `v` are the wrong size, you can transpose them or create them as 1*2 in the first place. Then use `0` as the scaling for quiver.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to retain the scatter plot before adding the vector plots.

```
theta = rand( 1, 2) * 2 * pi;

x1 = c(1) + 0.5 * [-1, 1] * cos( theta( 1));
y1 = c(2) + 0.5 * [-1, 1] * sin( theta( 1));
x2 = d(1) + 0.5 * [-1, 1] * cos( theta( 2));
y2 = d(2) + 0.5 * [-1, 1] * sin( theta( 2));

figure;
hold on;
plot( x1, y1, 'r')
plot( x2, y2, 'b')
plot( c(1), c(2), 'ro', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r');
plot( d(1), d(2), 'bo', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b');

xlim = get( gca, 'XLim');
ylim = get( gca, 'YLim');

lo = min( [xlim(1), ylim(1)]);
hi = max( [xlim(2), ylim(2)]);
axis equal
set( gca, 'XLim', [lo, hi], 'YLim', [lo, hi]);
```